# Any downside when using block_content as custom content entities?

Tags: 8, blocks

Background:
For a tourism project I need to integrate volatile data from external sources (like snow reports for ski ressorts or movies and their showtimes). This data should not be accessible by its own URL, they are always referenced/viewed from (mulitple) other traditional nodes (like a ski ressort node or a cinema node). Except for their ephemerality and the missing frontend URL they should work like any other node without revisions.

At first I thought I should create my own custom content entities.

But Custom content blocks seem to offer all I need (bundle-able, field-able, no own URL, multiple parents [rules out Paragraphs], integrate well with other modules like Views or Migrate, permissions,...) - for free without any custom coding (except I need to create/change some Admin UI views). There are going to be thousands of those data entries, and they will be updated frequently. But I do not intend to use them as blocks in the traditional Drupal way (placing them in regions).

Question:
Is there any downside when I "misuse" Custom content blocks as custom content entities in a large scale? The only downside I found is that those entries will massively clutter the block placement config window, but this seems acceptable.

Comment: I would do custom content entities personally. You can always disallow view access (so “view” route doesn’t matter), it’s queryable (requirements may change in the future?), and you won’t stuff up the block system with thousands of blocks.